# Why is my AJAX JQUERY trying to pass multiple variable values to php server side always returning an error?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, ajax

I am trying to send multiple values from the client side to the server side through JavaScript. Here is my JavaScript JQUERY function below:

```
// This function addToRentalCart(car) adds the requested
// car to a user's rental cart. It does this through the use
// of an AJAX call to the server with the required data.
// Since the required car data is already on the associated
// html webpage (index.html) all this function does is read it
// from there and send it to the server side process.
// Server side processing will then take care of the rest
// of the operation.

function addToRentalCart (car)
{
    var carPosition = 'carRow' + car;
    var carAvailabilityCol = 'Col10';
    var carAvailableElement = carPosition + carAvailabilityCol;
    var carAvailable = document.getElementById(carAvailableElement);
    
    if (carAvailable.innerHTML === 'N')
    {                                                         //If the car is not available
        alert("Sorry, the car is not available now. Please try other cars.");
    }
    else
    {                                                       //If the car is available
        //var carPictureFileCol = 'Col0';               //Set the column numbers of each desired variable
        var carMakeCol = 'Col1';
        var carModelCol = 'Col2';
        var carYearCol = 'Col3';
        var carPricePerDayCol = 'Col8';
        
        var carMakeElement = carPosition + carMakeCol;
        var carMake = document.getElementById(carMakeElement).innerHTML;   //Get the car make or brand
        
        var carModelElement = carPosition + carModelCol;
        var carModel = document.getElementById(carModelElement).innerHTML;      //Get the car model
        var carPictureFile = carModel + '.jpg';                           //Get the car picture file
        
        var carYearElement = carPosition + carYearCol;
        var carYear = document.getElementById(carYearElement).innerHTML;        //Get the car year
        
        var carPricePerDayElement = carPosition + carPricePerDayCol;
        var carPricePerDay = document.getElementById(carPricePerDayElement).innerHTML;
        carPricePerDay = carPricePerDay.substring(1);    //Get the price per day without the dollar sign
        $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "rentalCarsCart.php",
                data: {"carPicFile": carPictureFile, "carBrand": carMake, "carMod": carModel, 
                       "carYearMan": carYear, "carPPD": carPricePerDay},
                dataType: "json",
                success: function()
                {
                    alert("You have successfully added this car to your rental cart");
                },
                error: function()
                {
                    alert("error in Ajax call to cart url");
                },
            });
    }
}
```

All values seem fine even according to the Apache Netbeans IDE output but it bombs out and displays the error alert always. I have even debugged it inside Chrome developer tools using a breakpoint and step through method and all values are fine. It is bombing out inside JQUERY.JS itself and not sending the GET request to the PHP backend. Does anyone have any ideas why? I can't seem to find anything wrong with my code. If you can help me I would be grateful.

My server side code is as follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Rental Car Shopping Cart</title>
        <style>
            h1 {text-align: center;}
            button:hover{cursor: pointer;}
        </style>
    <h1>Car Reservation</h1>
    </head>
    <body>
        <?php
            header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
            
            $carPicture = $_GET['carPicFile']; // get car picture filename
            $carMake = $_GET['carBrand'];     // get the make of the car
            $carModel = $_GET['carMod'];      // get the car model
            $carYear = $_GET['carYearMan']; // Get the car year of manufacture
            $carPricePerDay = $_GET['carPPD'];    // Get the car price per day
            echo ('<div>');
            echo ($carPricePerDay);
            echo ('</div>');
        ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: what is the error? if you `error: function(err) { alert(err); }` then you'll get more information about what the error is

Comment: [object Object]

Comment: use console.log instead then -also, check the console for errors

Comment: The console has an error Unchecked runtime.lastError: The message port closed before a response was received. However this is on a different line in a different JavaScript function. That line is console.log(carsData);    // Send cars data as an array to the console log. However that is in a different JavaScript function used to get all cars from a JSON file, which works perfectly well already. I can even comment that line out and see what happens then.

Comment: the problem is on the server side

Comment: When I do comment it out. I still get Unchecked runtime.lastError: The message port closed before a response was received. but this time on index.html line 1 which is the <!DOCTYPE html> or first line of the html page. So does that mean the PHP is not sending back any response? Well it has to be called first does it not?

Comment: the problem is on the server side

Comment: I have added the server side code. It should at least execute it but I dont think it is. The reason is that I can not find the car price per day on the html php file, so I don't think it is even getting executed.

Comment: check the server side PHP logs for errors

Comment: How do I do that Jaromanda X? Sorry I am a newby with some things.

Comment: `dataType: "json",` means that jQuery expects a JSON response from your PHP but yours is HTML. Since you're not using the response any way, you might as well remove that setting

Comment: @JaromandaX the error callback accepts three arguments... `(jqXhr, textStatus, errorThrown)`. The first argument isn't particularly useful for logging

Comment: Thanks Phil. I have removed dataType: "json" as really I don't want any response back from php server side. That causes it to make a success function instead of the error function yet somehow I still feel my php is not even being called at all. Weird one!

Comment: @Phil - yeah, I'm used to using promise flavour of $.ajax :p

Comment: @SolimanSamirSoliman what makes you think that? Perhaps you should look at the actual response within your `success` handler

Comment: I may be wrong. I will try to increase the coding on the PHP side and then I will get back to you. If you want to make your response as a full blown answer I will mark it as correct. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Phil was right in the comment above that you don't need a dataType response from the PHP server side coding, so I removed it. I also found out the other problem on the PHP backend although not shown in the above PHP code which was very basic originally but got more complicated later:

```
Instead of if (($carPicture!=0) && ($carMake!=0) && ($carModel!=0) && ($carYear!=0) && 
  ($carPricePerDay!=0))
            {
                session_start();         //etc
Try:  
if (isset($carPicture) && isset($carMake) && isset($carModel) && isset($carYear) && isset($carPricePerDay))
            {
                session_start();           //etc
```

The reason being that when the variables are undefined they are also equal to zero or I am not sure why it decided to work with the bottom version. Positive logic seems to be better than negative logic for PHP. Thanks guys.